# How can I use the SVN?

Tags: java, svn

I am newbie to SVN, I have read [Link](http://www.institute.loni.org/lasigma/document_files/SVN_tutorial_Windows.pdf) but when I get to my java application code, and try to do svn add it says not enough arguments provided. what should I do?

My application is Java
I am using svn on Windows

Comment: You should probably [read some more](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.html)

Comment: What Java app are you using?  Just asking because most Java IDE's have svn support either built in or available as an extension.  Alternatively [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) is a very nice program to interact with svn repo's under windows, and a lot easier than the command line.

Comment: Have you consulted the manual for the command you're trying to execute?

Comment: I can use either netbeans or eclipse

Comment: Well, Netbeans has very good subversion support built in, and a [good tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html) as well, start by reading that tutorial.

Comment: Is that a more PC way to say RTFM, @alex?

Comment: @G.Bach hehe, I guess it is :)

Comment: How do I use the microwave? How do I use my keyboard to write a Java class?

Comment: If you're new to SVN, you might just as well have a look at more modern systems such as Git or HG which are conceptionally better at many things related to source code versioning.

Comment: @lucero they are not conceptually "better".

Comment: @bahrep, when I for instance look at the stiched together, brittle process of branching and merging branches with SVN, then yes, I have to say that those DVCS are conceptually better. In the end, time did not stand still and while SVN does have its merits, newer systems do have things they just do better, and more the way it should be.

Comment: @lucero "Anything you can do I can do better; I can do anything better than you" LOL ^__^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have a repository set up? if you don't have a repository that could be the other argument it's looking for